# Generate dynamic blocks in json request based on the regular expression array size in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where i am extracting `collectionId` and `solutionId` by using regular expression post processor for json request. These `collectionId` and `solutionId` will be used by further request as an input. My regex data could be of any size and based on this data size my API collection and solution block will increase or decrease. For instance, if regular expression is returning 3 `collectionid`s and 5 `solutionid`s then my api will consists 3 collection blocks:

```
{
  "CollectionId": ********,
  "StartTime": "*********",
  "EndTime": "*************",
  "ErrorCode": "*",
  "IsSuccess": true
}
```

and 5 solution blocks:

```
"SolutionSyncLog": [
{
  "SolutionId": ********,
  "Solution***": ********,
  "SolutionVersion": ********,
  "StartTime": "********",
  "EndTime": "********",
  "LastSyncUTC": "********",
  "ErrorCode": "0",
  "IsSuccess": true
}
]
```

In second run, if my regex returns 1 `collectionid` and 2 `solutionid` the my api will have 1 collection block and 2 solution block.

What should be the approach here? Please help anyone. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) with the "Compute concatenation var" option.

Comment: I am able to extract the values but the problem is based on the values returned my API request will vary the collectionid/solutionid blocks. If extractor returns 1 collection then API will hit with one block if 5 then 5 blocks will be added in API request.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the request payload using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class in the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor).

Example dynamic JSON generation:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)